# append letters with unique classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

So I'm hoping to append each letter of the alphabet either with a unique class or the same class but with a unique data value of that letter.
i have this

```
$('.letter').each(function(i){
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++) {
        $(this).append(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
});
```

which appends
ABCDEFGHIJK.....
into my existing 
so the final output is

```
<div class="letter">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
```

how can i make it so it appears as either:

```
<div class="letter-a">a</div>
<div class="letter-b">b</div>
<div class="letter-c">c</div>
```

or

```
<div class="letter" data-value="a">a</div>
<div class="letter" data-value="b">b</div>
<div class="letter" data-value="c">c</div>
<div class="letter" data-value="d">d</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div when you append

```
$('.letter').each(function(i){
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++) {
        $(this).append('<div class="letter-'+String.fromCharCode(i)+'">'+String.fromCharCode(i)+'</div>');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MuYWp/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var letters = $.trim($('.letter').text()).toLowerCase();
for (var i = 0, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('<div />', {
        'class': 'letter-' + letters[i],
        text: letters[i]
    }).appendTo('.letters');
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tXw4D/

Or to replace the existing `<div>`:

```
$('.letter').html(function(i, letters) {
    for (var i = 0, len = letters.length, html = ''; i < len; i++) {
        var letter = letters[i].toLowerCase();
        html += '<div class="letter-' + letter + '">' + letter + '</div>';
    }
    return html;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tXw4D/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.letter').each(function(i){
    for(var i=65;i<=90;i++) {
        var c = String.fromCharCode(i).toLowerCase();
        $(this).append("<div class='letter-"+c+"'>"+c+"</div>");
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bw38P/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.letter').replaceWith(function () {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    return $.map(text.split(''), function (char) {
        return '<div class="letter" data-value="' + char + '">' + char + '</div>';
    }).join('');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf7jT/)